Error al tratar de iniciar GNU octave en mac
hace poco volví a instalar octave en mac y a la hora lanzar el comando "octave" en la terminal me aparece este mensaje:
"Error 1 creating the settings file /Users/diegobravosoto/.config/ octave/octave-gui.ini
Make sure you have read and write permissions to
/Users/diegobravosoto/.config/ octave
Octave GUI must be closed now."
como lo puedo solucionar? no entiendo mucho de OSX
intente cambiando los permisos de escritura en los directorios que indica, pero no funciono.
